# Facebook app - desktop and mobile (responsive)

Tags: facebook, responsive-design, facebook-apps

I'm trying to build a facebook app. I think it would be nice if I could have a different design for a desktop view and a different design for a mobile view. I'm looking for some answers -

i) Is this even possible? 
ii) Can you refer me to any resources that I can read to find out more on how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

there are many front-end frameworks which help you to build both desktop and mobile websites
personally i use http://getbootstrap.com/ but there are many others, is up to you to chose the right one for your needs

Comment: That's for building responsive websites. I'm building a facebook application. Is it the same?

Comment: facebook has that canvas integration where basically your website is displayed within facebook, so yes, is the same in that case.
!!!note: for canvas you need app verification from facebook (see in app management) and an SSL cerificate.
!!!note2: if you don't like the ideea of resposive website you could use a mobile detect class/api like http://mobiledetect.net, this way you could detect if device is mobile/desktop and deliver different templates based on device